# Spark 2.0.0: SparkR CSV Import

Tags: csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sparkr

I am trying to read a csv file into SparkR (running Spark 2.0.0) - & trying to experiment with the newly added features.

Using RStudio here.

I am getting an error while "reading" the source file.

My code:

```
Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME = "C:/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.6")
library(SparkR, lib.loc = c(file.path(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), "R", "lib")))
sparkR.session(master = "local[*]", appName = "SparkR")
df <- loadDF("F:/file.csv", "csv", header = "true")
```

I get an error at at the loadDF function.

The error:

```
loadDF("F:/file.csv", "csv", header = "true")
```

> Error in invokeJava(isStatic = TRUE, className, methodName, ...) : 
>         java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:258)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:359)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:263)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSharedState.metadataHive$lzycompute(HiveSharedState.scala:39)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSharedState.metadataHive(HiveSharedState.scala:38)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSharedState.externalCatalog$lzycompute(HiveSharedState.scala:46)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSharedSt

Am I missing some specification here? Any pointers to proceed would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem.
But similary problem with this simple code

```
createDataFrame(iris)
```

May be some wrong in installation ?

UPD. YES ! I find solution.

This solution based on this: [Apache Spark MLlib with DataFrame API gives java.net.URISyntaxException when createDataFrame() or read().csv(...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38746340/apache-spark-mllib-with-dataframe-api-gives-java-net-urisyntaxexception-when-cre)

For R just start session by this code:

```
sparkR.session(sparkConfig = list(spark.sql.warehouse.dir="/file:C:/temp"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try reading the CSV with this library

https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv

```
Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME = "C:/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.6")

library(SparkR, lib.loc = c(file.path(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), "R", "lib")))

sparkR.session(master = "local[*]", appName = "SparkR")  

Sys.setenv('SPARKR_SUBMIT_ARGS'='"--packages" "com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.4.0" "sparkr-shell"')

sqlContext <- sparkRSQL.init(sc)

df <- read.df(sqlContext, "cars.csv", source = "com.databricks.spark.csv", inferSchema = "true")
```

Comment: Hi Erick, thank you for the response. But as I gather, Spark 2.0.0 has native "csv" suport which is why I tried exploring how we could "read" csv files directly. In addition, Spark 2.0.0 now uses "SparkR.session" method for initialization and sqlContext usage has been deprecated. (On their official webpage, they say one can directly operate on data frames without using sqlContext!) I am kind of lost because I get errors when I try to execute the examples. :(

Comment: spark-csv was indeed merged into Spark2, with some minor changes. The packaged should be considered legacy software - as your Github link also indicates.