# Apache Spark MLlib with DataFrame API gives java.net.URISyntaxException when createDataFrame() or read().csv(...)

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

In a standalone application (runs on java8, Windows 10 with spark-xxx_2.11:2.0.0 as jar dependencies) next code gives an error:

```
/* this: */
Dataset<Row> logData = spark_session.createDataFrame(Arrays.asList(
    new LabeledPoint(1.0, Vectors.dense(4.9,3,1.4,0.2)),
    new LabeledPoint(1.0, Vectors.dense(4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2))
  ), LabeledPoint.class);

/* or this: */
/* logFile: "C:\files\project\file.csv", "C:\\files\\project\\file.csv",
            "C:/files/project/file.csv", "file:/C:/files/project/file.csv",
            "file:///C:/files/project/file.csv", "/file.csv" */
Dataset<Row> logData = spark_session.read().csv(logFile);
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: file:C:/files/project/spark-warehouse
               at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.initialize(Path.java:206)
               at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:172)
               at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.makeQualifiedPath(SessionCatalog.scala:114)
               at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.createDatabase(SessionCatalog.scala:145)
               at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.<init>(SessionCatalog.scala:89)
               at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionState.catalog$lzycompute(SessionState.scala:95)
               at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionState.catalog(SessionState.scala:95)
               at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionState$$anon$1.<init>(SessionState.scala:112)
               at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionState.analyzer$lzycompute(SessionState.scala:112)
               at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionState.analyzer(SessionState.scala:111)
               at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:49)
               at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:64)
               at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.createDataFrame(SparkSession.scala:373)
               at <call in my line of code>
```

How can I load csv file into `Dataset<Row>` from java code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some issue with file system path. See jira https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-15899. For workaround you can set "spark.sql.warehouse.dir" in SparkSession like below.

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("JavaALSExample")
  .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "/file:C:/temp")
  .getOrCreate();
```

Comment: Hard to beleive, but issue's severity is 'Minor'. This workaround solves my error, thanks!